# Got serious problem with my J530F need quick help

Tags: adb

i've got really hard problem with my j5 which is probably totally bricked. But. there is but, i can access recovery mode and connect it to the ADB, but still, aint that easy. While trying to flash new ROM, im getting up to 40 % and its shows "e:signature verification failed" after that it gets to 92% and stops. Total xfer: 2.00x on phone it shows as "E:failed to find /misc partition".
I've been trying literally everything.
Weird thing, cannot open adb shell, "error:closed" been trying killing server, starting server etc.

Most weird thing is J5 CANNOT ACCESS THE "DOWNLOAD MODE" which is the biggest problem in my case.
apart from that, i've got no TWRP or CMW installd, only stock recovery mode, whatever option im trying to get into, always gets same info "E:Failed to find /misc partition".
what else... I've been trying to make SD card as bootable device with android on it, if you've got any ideas about that, im happy to hear.
been trying several rooms, stock, lineage, other customs.
Tried several versions of adb..
sometimes adb shows info "deamon not started" which after i've got communicate that deamon started succesfully and transfered to port 500 something.

Please guys, help me with that. I've wasted about 60 over hours now  getting sick.